# CKAN with data access only after login

Tags: ckan, fiware

Can CKAN be used for a website where users only get access to the datasets after login?

I have in mind a site like [www.statista.com](http://www.statista.com) run with CKAN that gives users access to only a few datasets. Full access is granted after signing in (e.g., to users who are paying for a subscription). Is that possible with CKAN?

If that is possible, does CKAN have its own authentication system or can it be managed with FIWARE Key Rock GE and Access Control GE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKAN has its own authentication system, but we have developed a extension that allows developers to use some IdM (including the FIWARE one) to authenticate the users. If you want to use this extension you can check the instructions for installing it on https://github.com/conwetlab/ckanext-oauth2

We have also developed another extension to manage the users that can view a specific dataset. However, I think this extension does not fit to your purposes, but you can develop your own extension (as stated by Kapucko). It's very easy, you have to follow the instructions provided on http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/tutorial.html.

In your case you will have to implement the `IAuthFunctions` plugin interface, overwrite the `package_show` function and return `{ 'success': True }` only when the user is logged in. I seem to remember that this only happens when `context.get('auth_user_obj') is not None`.

You can also use organizations and create all the datasets within it (setting the `Visibility` field to `Private`). Nevertheless, I do not recommend you this approach since you will have to manually insert new users.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom extensions for CKAN, where you can define your custom authentication.
A good point where to start is: https://ckan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/maintaining/authorization.html