# Request private CKAN resource with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ckan

I would like to get a private CKAN resource (a CSV file) from a client side application avoiding the use of the api key, i.e. using username and password (I have already checked adding the api key as header and it works well).

I've been searching other similar questions and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360247/ckan-with-data-access-only-after-login/27932651#27932651) (which could be the final answer) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271351/download-resources-from-private-ckan-datasets) (using Python). Sorry if this question has been already answered elsewhere. However, I wanted to give a try avoiding server side solutions, so I've been trying the following request using jQuery:

*Where `pattern` function is to replace parameters in the input string and `login` the object that would store user's input.

```
$.ajax({
    url: pattern('{ckanUrl}/dataset/{pkg}/resource/{resource}/download/{fileName}', dataset),
    type: 'GET',
    username: login.username,
    password: login.password,
    data: {
        //login: login.username,
        //password: login.password,
        cache: true
    },
    dataType: 'text'
})
.done(function(res) {
    console.log('success!!');
})
.fail(function(res) {
    console.log('fail!!');
});
```

`pattern` function takes `dataset` object and adds its attributes as parameters in the given string. e.g.:

```
var dataset = {
    ckanUrl: 'https://myckan.org',
    pkg: 'packageId',
    resource: 'resourceId',
    fileName: 'myFile.csv'
};

pattern('{ckanUrl}/dataset/{pkg}/resource/{resource}/download/{fileName}', dataset)  
// "https://myckan.org/dataset/packageId/resource/resourceId/download/myFile.csv"
```

I have also tried adding credentials inside data attribute (commented above), but no success. I get `404 (Not found)` error in any case.

Am I missing something or is this not possible with CKAN?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `pattern()` actually returning?  A 404 indicates the resource wasn't found, implying your URL is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Amy, thanks for your answer. I added some explanation on pattern function. The same function works well with public resources so I would assume the issue is not there unless I'm not using the correct IDs (which I hope not) or the URL structure (first parameter of the function) varies.
I found out that CKAN also returns 404 when trying to download something and you are not logged in.